# Geometry nodes , how to select specific parts of object and delete it?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces, edges, selection-tools, select

i need to delete the faces and have a clean boundary. i can't figure it out how to select them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
(blender 3.6.1)

this shape is a base floor plan for creating a procedural building. something like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please manually model the result you want to achieve. Currently this is how I understand your question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a floor plan for generating procedural buildings, and those edges which extruded inside is for balcony on other floors.

Comment: @Pooyaheydari *"Please manually model the result you want to achieve."* - I meant this is a simple enough shape, that you can manually model it, and obviously for some reason you're using geonodes, but if you model it manually, we then know what you want to achieve in geonodes and can advise properly. Is this answer not helpful, not what you were aiming for?

Comment: thank u, i updated my question. i think it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with this node setup to select faces by their normals.

and this is the result :

[image]